React E-commerce Shop, products not staying when login out of an account
SO im trying to get the products selected to appear in my Cart Page even if a I log out of the account, that they stay in the database for the respective user. But i think is because of the variable size that impeeding that, I was trying to add but being novice in react and mongo db failed.
I tried changing the db but atlas on my websitedidn't update...
The mongo db code as of now
//Create API for user
const Users = mongoose.model('Users', {
    name:{
        type: String,
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        unique:true,
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
    },
    cartData:{
        type:Object,
    },

    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now,
    }
})

And I changed it to this in my back end
const Users = mongoose.model('Users', { 
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    cartData: {
        type: Map,
        of: {
            type: Object,
            default: {
                S: { type: Number, default: 0 },
                M: { type: Number, default: 0 },
                L: { type: Number, default: 0 },
                XL: { type: Number, default: 0 },
                XXL: { type: Number, default: 0 },
            },
        },
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
});


My addtocart API
// Endpoint to add products to cart data
app.post('/addtocart', fetchUser, async (req, res) => {

    console.log("added", req.body.jerseyId);
    try {
        const { jerseyId } = req.body;
        
        if (!jerseyId) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Item ID is required" });
        }

        let userData = await Users.findOne({ _id: req.user.id });

        // Initialize the item in the cart if it doesn’t exist
        if (!userData.cartData[jerseyId]) {
            userData.cartData[jerseyId] = 0;
        }

        userData.cartData[jerseyId] += 1;

        await Users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.user.id }, { cartData: userData.cartData });
        
        res.json({ success: true, message: "Item added to cart successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding item to cart:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "An error occurred while adding the item to the cart" });
    }
});


front-end that calls API
const addToCart = (jerseyId, size) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [jerseyId]: {
            ...prev[jerseyId],
            [size]: (prev[jerseyId][size] || 0) + 1, // Increment the quantity for the selected size
        },
    }));

    if (localStorage.getItem('auth-token')) {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/addtocart', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'auth-token': localStorage.getItem('auth-token'),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ jerseyId, size }), // Now sending both jerseyId and size
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
    }
};

How cart page look (just in case)
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import './CartItems.css'; // Importing the CSS file for styling.
import { ShopContext } from '../../Context/ShopContext'; // Importing ShopContext to access cart-related functions and data.
import remove_icon from '../Assets/remove_icon.jpg'; // Remove item icon.

const CartItems = () => {
    const { getTotalCartAmount, every_product, cartItems, removeFromCart } = useContext(ShopContext); // Accessing cart context.

    return (
        <div className='cartitems'>
            {/* Header row for cart item details */}
            <div className="cartitems-format-main">
                <p>Products</p>
                <p>Title</p>
                <p>Size</p> {/* Added Size column */}
                <p>Price</p>
                <p>Quantity</p>
                <p>Total</p>
               {/*  <p>Remove</p> */}
            </div>
            <hr />

            {/* Mapping over the products to display each cart item */}
            {every_product.map((e) => {
                // Check if there is any item of this product in the cart for any size
                const productInCart = Object.keys(cartItems[e.id]).filter(size => cartItems[e.id][size] > 0);

                // Only display products with a quantity greater than 0 for any size
                return productInCart.length > 0 ? (
                    <div key={e.id}>
                        {productInCart.map((size) => (
                            <div className="cartitems-format cartitems-format-main" key={size}>
                                {/* Product image */}
                                <img 
                                    src={e.image || 'default_image_path.jpg'} 
                                    alt={e.name} 
                                    className='carticon-product-icon' 
                                />
                                <p>{e.name}</p> {/* Product name */}
                                <p>{size}</p> {/* Display selected size */}
                                <p>${e.us_cost}</p> {/* Product price */}

                                {/* Quantity button */}
                                <button className='cart-items-quantity'>
                                    {cartItems[e.id][size]} {/* Display quantity for the selected size */}
                                </button> 

                                {/* Total price for the product based on quantity and size */}
                                <p>${e.us_cost * cartItems[e.id][size]}</p>

                                {/* Remove from cart button */}
                                <img 
                                    src={remove_icon} 
                                    onClick={() => removeFromCart(e.id, size)} 
                                    alt="Remove item" 
                                    className='cart-items-remove-icon' 
                                />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                ) : null; // Explicitly return null if no items for this product
            })}
            
            {/* Section for cart total and checkout */}
            <div className="cart-items-down">
                <div className="cartitems-total">
                    <h1>Totals</h1>
                    <div>
                        {/* Subtotal */}
                        <div className="cartitems-total-item">
                            <p>Subtotal</p>
                            <p>${getTotalCartAmount()}</p> {/* Total cost of all items in the cart */}
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        
                        {/* Shipping fee */}
                        <div className="cartitems-total-item">
                            <p>Shipping Fee</p>
                            <p>Free Shipping!</p>
                        </div>    
                        <hr />
                        
                        {/* Grand total */}
                        <div className="cartitems-total-item">
                            <h3>Total</h3>
                            <h3>${getTotalCartAmount()}</h3> {/* Grand total after shipping */}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    {/* Proceed to checkout button */}
                    <button className="cart-items-checkout-button">PROCEED TO CHECKOUT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CartItems;


Could you share your logout method? I think that's the most important one.  Also very quick view at your code is you are attaching the cartItems to the user, so when you logout the cart is empty/gone, because there probably isn't a user anymore.
What I see e-commerce webshops do is to separate the cart from the user, so the user_id property of a cart can be empty. You can then store the cart_id in the session and don't drop that variable when logging out.
